# How to transmit c++ strucure from dll to c# program?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

I have DLL, written in C++. There is structure in this DLL.

```
typedef struct TransmitData
{
wchar_t    szPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD      dwResult;
} *lpTransmitData;
```

And I have one function to fill this struct

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetData(struct TransmitData &data)
{
//I HAVE ONE THE SAME STRUCT IN THIS DLL
memcpy(&data, &transmitData, sizeof(struct TransmitData));
return ret_value;
}
```

In C# program I use functions with simple data types well, but for structure it doesn't work. There is code on C#:

```
public struct TransmitData
{
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 260)] //260 = MAX_PATH
public string szPath;
public uint dwResult;
}
//...
[DllImport("MyDLL")]
public static extern int GetData(ref TransmitData data);
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to set your [struct layout to sequential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx).

Comment: "it doesn't work" What does that mean? Doesn't compile?  An exception?  What is the error/exception message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to replace

```
[DllImport("MyDLL")]
```

with

```
[DllImport("MyDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

and

```
extert "C"
```

with

```
extern "C"
```

Moreover, as Joe suggested, add

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
```

before the declaration of the struct in C# code

Comment: Answers starting with words like "try" should not be answers but comments

Comment: sorry, that was misprint (extern "C"), but only here, in code all ok)
and other functions works correct, like int func(), etc...

Comment: @Lex, you should consider using the `__stdcall` calling convention for DLL exported functions, it's the most common for such. It's rather much like the answer, i.e. to match calling conventions, but you'd fix it in the C/C++ file.